# Change barStyle required tap screen to change Status Bar text

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have my viewController embed in a custom NavigationController that used one instance for the whole app, currently the `barStyle` is `Default`, i wanted to change a screen status bar to white text, so i changed the `barStyle` to `Black`, it worked well, but it never change before the first tap in the screen, unsure what's the problem :/

The code is putting in `viewDidLoad`

Please help if anyone had this issue before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UINavigationBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/) is an entity that inherits his properties from `UIView`

To force the re-render/refresh of his structure (essentially to re-call `drawRect` function) you can write:

```
myNavigationController.navigationBar.setNeedDisplay()
```

Comment: I tried `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` also seems to work